# Finite Projective Planes - The Prime Power Conjecture, Why is This Difficult?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups

A projective plane consists of a set of points, $\mathcal{P},$ a set of lines $\mathcal{L}$ and a relation $\mathbf{I}$ between points and lines called *incidence* having the following relation, denoted $\left(\mathcal{P},\mathcal{L},\mathbf{I}\right)$: (***1***) Given any two distinct points, there is exactly one line incident with both of them. (***2***) Given any two distinct lines, there is exactly one point incident with both of them. (***3***) There are four points such that no line is incident with more than two of them. It can be shown that a projective plane, finite or otherwise has an equal number of points and lines. Thus, for every finite projective plane there is an integer $N≥2$ such that the plane has $N^{2}+N+1$ points and lines and $N + 1$ points on each line and through each point. The number $N$ is called the order of the projective plane.

It can be shown the number of $1-$dimensional and $2-$ dimensional subspaces of the vector space $\mathbf{F}^{3}_{q}$ is equal to 
$$
\frac{q^3-1}{q-1}=q^2+q+1.
$$
If a $1-$dimensional subspace is contained in a $2-$ dimensional subspace we say they are incident. In particular we can construct an [incident relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_structure) $\left( \mathcal{P},\mathcal{L},\mathbf{I}\right),$ where $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{L}$ are the $1$ and $2$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbf{F}^{3}_{q}$ respectively and the relation $\mathbf{I}$ is subspace containment. From this we see that a finite projective plane of order $q$ is a $2-\left(q^2+q+1,q+1,1\right)$ [design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design). Usually this design is denoted by $PG\left(2,q\right).$ Following *this* vector space construction  there exist a finite plane of order $N=q^{n}$ for each prime number $q.$

Indeed it appears the only finite projective planes that are known are of prime power order. And it has been conjectured that any *finite projective plane must have prime power order*. This conjecture is apparently still open. A great deal of work in studying the structure (existence, [ovals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oval_(projective_plane)) etc.) of finite projective planes involves tools from the character and modular representation theory of finite groups. A major result in the field is the [Bruck–Ryser–Chowla:](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/2A2E0D91C8E872232A01C7519F14D705/S0008414X00028686a.pdf/nonexistence_of_certain_finite_projective_planes.pdf) If a finite projective plane of order $q$ exists and $q\equiv 1,2\pmod 4$, then $q$ must be the sum of two squares. This result for example can be used rule out a finite projective plane of order 6.

> **Question**: What makes this conjecture difficult to solve?

Explicitly I am asking where are the stumbling blocks, no pun intended, within finite group and combinatorial ***theory*** that has made this problem impossible to conquer ? Incidentally, no pun I swear, there is an extensive body of literature devoted to computational aspects of finite projective planes. A great deal of work has been done establishing the (non-)existence of finite projective planes with or without prescribed properties. None of those efforts have resolved the conjecture.

---

Update:

This is a response to a series of comments written by @verret:

Following Brauer, Alberts, [Hall](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1943-054-02/S0002-9947-1943-0008892-4/S0002-9947-1943-0008892-4.pdf) ,Thompson and others a great body of research on finite projective planes has been approached ostensibly by the character theory and modular representation theory of finite groups. Since the time this conjecture was stated group theorist have: (**1**) classified all finite simple groups and (**2**) built a great machinery around the representation of finite groups. From the combinatorial side we have deep results from *Combinatorial Commutative Algebra* and the study of posets. Yet this conjecture remains unsolved. What is central to this conjecture that has escaped some of the best advancements of finite group theory and combinatorics ?

Comment: I think the answer is that it is difficult because nobody has any idea how to go about proving it. It was proved in the late 1980s by a huge computer search that there is no projective plane of order 10, but anything beyond that is beyond the power of naive computation.

Comment: There's no indication that this problem has anything to do with group theory.

Comment: Curiously, there are four different projective planes of order 9.

Comment: @verret Finite group theory is must definitely germain to the study of finite projective planes. From the study of collineations to ovals and the study of their incident matrices. Ditto the study of Steiner Systems, triples and Latin Squares which with under specified parameters are known to be equivalent to finite projective planes. My understanding is this problem sits at the intersection of finite group theory and combinatorics. For example [1](http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/psl2q.pdf)

Comment: As with many long-standing open problems, we actually do not really know if they are difficult and why, until somebody solves the problem and even then it is not always clear. A good example is the Bieberbach Conjecture: It was open for 69 years, the first proof (by de Branges) was about 500 pages long and had small mistakes; eventually, a proof under 10 pages was given by Grinshpan. As for the Prime Power Conjecture, for all we known, some smart undergraduate student can construct a counter-example.

Comment: @AntonioHernandezMaquivar I didn't say that group theory is not useful in this area, just that it is unlikely (IMO) to be important in resolving this conjecture. For a similar example, consider Steiner triple systems, which you brought up. The smallest one is the Fano Plane, which definitely has many connections to group theory. As one expands the search, one gets examples with fewer and fewer symmetries, until we get a combinatorial explosion of examples with trivial automorphism group (and no group involved in any natural way).

Comment: Therefore, if you want to study general STS (as opposed to specific examples), group theory is not helpful. (And you will see this is born out in the literature.) The situation is similar for PPs. The first examples are classical with very tight links to group theory (and other various parts of algebra). The next examples discovered had slightly less symmetry, and so on. Try to look at the list of known projective planes of order 16 for example. They were more or less discovered in decreasing order of size of automorphism groups. (If there's a big group involved, it's easier to find.)

Comment: Now we know some with (relatively) small groups, and it's quite possible that there are some asymmetric ones, perhaps even that these are the majority, just as for STS. (I am aware of the fundamental difference between the two cases, related to how the parameters grow.) There is thus no reason to believe that group theory can be useful to resolving a question about the existence of general projective planes, since one would have to rule out the existence of projective planes with trivial groups.

Comment: Of course, with these things, one can never be sure until one has a proof, but, given that there is no groups involved in the definition of projective plane, and nobody has managed to show the existence of any important group for general projective planes, I feel the onus is on those who feel a group should be involved to justify that.

Comment: Of course, with these things, one can never be sure until one has a proof, but, given that there is no groups involved in the definition of projective plane, and nobody has managed to show the existence of any important group for general projective planes, I feel the onus is on those who feel a group should be involved to justify that.

Comment: For more evidence, look at the existing non-existence results (as that is what we are after here):  Bruck–Ryser–Chowla and the non-existence of a projective plane of order 10. Neither of them involve any group theory. Again, it may be that we are missing something and there is a group-theoretical approach but, at the moment, there even isn't a group! (I think Moishe has an interesting counterpoint: if the Conjecture is false and a counter-example is produced, it's possible that the construction might involve some group theory. But this applies to almost any area of math.)

Comment: @AntonioHernandezMaquivar By the way, I just had a look at the paper you linked. It's a perfect example to prove my point! The results there ASSUME the existence of a nice group acting on the plane, and then derive some results. No wonder group theory is involved!  But we already know many examples of planes without nice groups, and there are probably even more. It's like saying that group theory should play an important role in structural graph theory because of vertex-transitive graphs...

Comment: Group theory aside, I think that questions of the type "Why is this famous conjecture difficult?" not appropriate for this site. The answers usually boil down to "because no-one knows how to do it", so I'm voting to close. (It might be different for a more specific question, about a particular approach or specific difficulty.)